# Можно ли форматировать раздел при такой структуре?

Tags: ubuntu, разметка, root

```
Диск /dev/sda: 500.1 Гб, 500107862016 байт
255 головок, 63 секторов/треков, 60801 цилиндров, всего 976773168 секторов
Units = секторы of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Размер сектора (логического/физического): 512 байт / 512 байт
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Идентификатор диска: 0x57423fe9

Устр-во Загр     Начало       Конец       Блоки   Id  Система
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848    84019199    41906176    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        84020011   976771071   446375530+   5  Расширенный
/dev/sda5        84020013   889326269   402653128+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       889326333   940343295    25508481+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       940345344   976771071    18212864   83  Linux
```

Можно ли удалить sda6 для дальнейшего его объединения с sda7 (без потери данных на sda7)?

Когда я «захожу» в `gparted`, он пишет, что надо размонтировать все разделы, которые идут после 6, а у меня sda7 - корень.

Comment: нумерация разделов не говорит ничего о порядке их расположения на диске. приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу вывод команды `sudo fdisk  -l /dev/sda`. исправить вопрос можно, нажав [edit].

Comment: Можно, с флэшки, но будет очень долго, т.к. будет двигать все данные с корня в начало нового раздела. Вообще, не очень хороша по быстродействию схема, когда основная структура диска создаётся виндой. Кстати, при попытке изменить что-то штатными средствами окон, убьются все linux разделы(!).

Comment: > leks  Кстати, при попытке изменить что-то штатными средствами окон, убьются все linux разделы(!).

то есть штатными средствами? даже если я создам гпартед флешку и загружусь с неё? на счет структуры да, просто не всегда у нас бывает выбор.

Comment: Штатными- это "управление дисками" или как там у них в окнах. Live флешка это любой удобный образ linux дистра.

Comment: Да, при восстановлении винды из предустановленного образа, с переформатированием диска `C`, также может все не свои разделы по... (лишить файловой системы).

Comment: leks, у меня сда6 он по сути пустой, что если удалить раздел и расширить сда7 через фдиск когда рут будет не смонтирован, есть какие-то нежелательные последствия? винду это никак не заденет, на этом диске(сда6) сейчас 1.5гб роликов видео никаких сис файлов

Answer (score 1):

да, всё верно предлагает вам программа `gparted`: при перемещения файловой системы, записанной внутри раздела, на другое место, файловая система должна быть отмонтирована.

загрузитесь с любого *live*/*rescue*-носителя, в котором есть программа `gparted`, и переместите информацию так, как требуется.

---

рекомендация на будущее: пользуйтесь возможностями [*lvm*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LVM).

в этом случае вы могли «вживую», без перезагрузок и *live*/*rescue*-носителей:

1. изменить (лишь для вашего удобства) «тип» раздела *sda6* на *8e (linux lvm)* — с помощью `fdisk`, `*parted` или любого подобного инструмена.
2. инициализировать этот раздел как физический том (*physical volume*) с помощью `pvcreate`.
3. добавить этот раздел к вашей группе томов (*volume group*) с помощью `vgextend`.
4. увеличить размер логического тома (*logical volume*) с помощью `lvextend`.
5. увеличить размер файловой системы *ext* с помощью `resize2fs`.