# Как разделить диск в kali linux?

Tags: linux, файловая-система, разметка, диск, разметка-диска

Есть раздел /dev/sda1 который надо разделить, когда пытаюсь размонтировать ругается что занят.
Я пытался что-то сделать, но остался один раздел   /dev/sda1

> # umount -v '/' 
> umount: /: target is busy.

Comment: фактически про то же: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/443606/178576

Comment: Я как понимаю вы из под рабочей системы пытаетесь отсортировать раздел на котором она работает??? Ну так и не получится.